# Is it overkill to use two way assignment with WAI-ARIA Properties?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is it repetitive/overkill, better or worse to use a two way assignment with *aria-properties*? for example using an `aria-control` and an `aria-labelledby`?

```
<div role="tablist">
  <a href="#" id="tab-1" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1">Tab 1</a>
</div>

<div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok to do this and it is also ok to not do this. The reason it is ok to not do this are:

Firstly: role `tabpanel` is a region role and does not require a label, so having no label is ok.
Secondly: You should create something focusable inside your tab panel (e.g. the first heading) so that a user can tab directly from the selected tab into the tab panel. When they do this, the focus goes straight to the focusable element. This means that the tab panel label would never get read.

The argument in favor of doing this is that a screen reader user, using DOM navigation, would encounter the tab panel and know which tab is selected without having to navigate to the tab itself.